# This function is running but why does it not return the <div> inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a function 'renderComments()' which takes in an array of comments and returns the comments displayed within in a Card that is inside a . Howevere, when the function runs, the function html code is not displayed on this React page, why?
NB: The last render of the page works perfectly, just the renderComments() function is not displaying on the page. The props' comments do exist as I can see them on the console log.

```
    import {Component} from "react";
import {Card, CardBody, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardTitle} from "reactstrap";
import React from "react";
import CardColumns from "reactstrap/es/CardColumns";

class DishDetail extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // refers to the properties of the component that we can make use of


}

renderComments(comments) {
    comments.map((comment) => {
        if (comment != null){
        return (
            <div className={'row'}>
                <Card className={"col-12 col-md-5 m-1"}>
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardText> {comment.comment} </CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )}
        else{
            return <div></div>
        }
    });



}


render() {
    // Props is the saved state from the constructor (from the app.js file which
    // gave the DISHES data to the menu component, (which imported it from
    // the DISHES.js file)).


    if (this.props.selectedDish != null) {
        const commentsRet = this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish.comments)
        return (

        <div>
            <div>
            <Card className={"col-12 col-md-5 m-1"}>
                <CardImg top src={this.props.selectedDish.image} alt={this.props.selectedDish.name}/>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle> {this.props.selectedDish.name} </CardTitle>
                    <CardText> {this.props.selectedDish.description} </CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
            </div>
            <div>
                {commentsRet}
            </div>
        </div>


        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }

}
```

}

export default DishDetail;

[image: Page shot]

Comments which should appear to the right (from the return of the function):

```
comments: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    rating: 5,
                    comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                    author: "John Lemon",
                    date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    rating: 4,
                    comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                    author: "Paul McVites",
                    date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    rating: 3,
                    comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                    author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                    date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    rating: 4,
                    comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                    author: "Ringo Starry",
                    date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    rating: 2,
                    comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                    author: "25 Cent",
                    date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by pure? How would I make it return the div?

Comment: You can use the `return` keyword to return expressions to the caller

Comment: I see what you mean now! However this still doesnt result in the div being shown on the page (see screenshot where the comments should appear on the right of the card)

Comment: console.log `this.props.selectedDish` - I'm willing to bet it's empty...

Comment: I put a console.log(comment) in the returnComment() function and it showed the full comments just as it is supposed to. Sadly I think it's something I'm doing wrong with displaying the html but it's hard to say as I'm new to react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only `return` statement you have is inside the arrow function you pass as an argument to `map`.

The `renderComments` function itself has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Add `return` before `comments.map`.

Comment: I've just added return into the function but this still hasn't fixed the issue - screenshot as uploaded above shows the original card but not the extra div with the comments from the function

Comment: I have opened up the page the following day and now it is loading as it should strangely enough! Must have just not been reloading the page properly.